# This function should return true if a vector contains repeats. Any idea why it isn't working?

Tags: c++

I thought this was pretty straight-forward, but it returned true when I passed it this vector:

```
   int arr2[] =  {1, 6, 7, 89, 69, 23, 19, 100, 8, 2, 50, 3, 11, 90};               
   std::vector<int> vec2(arr2, arr2 + sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(int));
```

The algorithm is simply:

(1) Instantiate a map.
(2) For each int in the vector, 
(2i) if it isn't in the map, add it, 
(2ii) and if it is in the map, return true. 
(3) Return false if the end of the for 
loop is reached.

```
bool contains_repeats_1(const std::vector<int>& V) { 
    std::map<int,bool> M;
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = V.begin(); it != V.end(); it++) {
        if (M.count(*it) != 0) { 
             M.insert(std::pair<int,bool>(*it, true));
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Also, I would appreciate any suggestions about how to better solve this problem. I'm using Apple XCode and it doesn't have the library that contains unordered_map.

Comment: `if it isn't in the map, add it` I think that you're actually doing the opposite with `if (M.count(*it) != 0)`

Comment: Many C++ implementations that don't have `unordered_map` have a `hash_map` which is similar.

Answer (score 3):

Easier:

```
std::set<int> s(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
return s.size() < vec2.size();
```

This relies on the fact that an `std::set` contains no duplicated. So if there are any duplicates in the vector, the set will be smaller.

If you are concerned that this performs too many unnecessary copies, you can use a loop and break out at the first duplicate:

```
std::set<int> s;
for (int i : vec2) {
  if (!s.insert(i).second) return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: That would be less efficient in terms of computation time and memory.

Comment: @user2943949 I added an alternative that breaks out after the first duplicate. Up to you to test both and see which one is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::sort(V.begin(), V.end());
if (std::adjacent_find(V.begin(), V.end()) != V.end()) {
    // found a duplicate
}
```